How to show context menu in Flet when I right-click on a ListTile or a Text Control
Using Flet package in python (desktop application), I am trying to show a context menu when a user right clicks on a label (usually a Text or a ListTile Control). The context menu should be customizable with custom options, unlike the one you get in a TextField Control with "cut", "copy", "paste" and "select all" options.
I tried searching though Flet documentation to find a right-click event available in a control but could not find any (including GestureDetector). One of the alternatives for a context menu I found was to use a PopupMenuButton in a ListTile as a trailing control. But it would be best to find a right-click event for a control to be used in my application.

It's not currently supported. See https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues/1804 for updates
